# Проверка двух последних элементов в input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как проверить последние два элемента в строке `input` на знак операции? Нужно отделить в строке число от знака и если знаков два (+-), то записать последний (-). Как я понял, нужно в `if` просто добавить условия:

```
function changeAction(value)
{   
    //var input = document.getElementById("t");

    var onlyNumbers = /[\/*+-]{2}/; //пееревірка чи введені не цифри

    if (onlyNumbers.test(calculator.answer.value))
    {    
        alert("lol2");
        if (calculator.answer.value =='++' || calculator.answer.value == '-+' || calculator.answer.value =='/+' || calculator.answer.value =='*+')
        {
            calculator.answer.value = (calculator.answer.value.substr(0,calculator.answer.value.length -2));
            //alert(calculator.answer.value.substr(0,calculator.answer.value.length-2));
        }

        if (calculator.answer.value =='--' || calculator.answer.value == '/-' || calculator.answer.value =='*-' || calculator.answer.value =='+-')
        {
            calculator.answer.value = '-';
        }

        if (calculator.answer.value =='-*' || calculator.answer.value == '/*' || calculator.answer.value =='**' || calculator.answer.value =='+*')
        {
            calculator.answer.value = '*';
        }

        if (calculator.answer.value =='//' || calculator.answer.value == '*/' || calculator.answer.value =='-/' || calculator.answer.value =='+/')
        {
            calculator.answer.value = '/';
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function handler(){
  let text = document.querySelector('#test'),
      reg;
  
  // Ищем в конце знаки +, -, *, /, сколько бы их не было
  // Проверку на то, является ли строка числом с знаками, можно, при желании, вставить потом
  reg = /^([^\-\+*\/]*)([\-\+*\/]+)$/.exec(text.value.trim());
  
  // Если они есть, вставляем содержимое ДО знаков и самый последний из введённых
  // some+-+--+ -> some+
  // some+-+ -> some+
  // some+--+- -> some-
  if(reg !== null){
    text.value = reg[1] + reg[2][reg[2].length - 1];
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.querySelector('#check').addEventListener('click', handler);
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='test' /><br />
<input type='button' id='check' value='Проверить' />
```

Comment: Спасибо..работает  + - ,но * и / не работает,в чем дело?

Comment: @Archi, добавлять остальные знаки можно в регулярку. Там только плюс и минус, а самих знаков куча: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2 Выбирай любой и добавляй :)